# Array, List or DataTable for use with a DataGridView (Windows.Forms) and filtering

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm reading at the momment from several sources (csv Files,..) data to a array and then via foreach() { .Add(..) } to a DatagridView.

Now i want to have the possibility, to search the Data in the control by a textfield-input by the user.

Might here be the best way i make a DataTable instead an array or such a `GenericList<T>` in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datatable

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
```

Binding Datatable using BindingSource

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
bs.DataSource = table;
```

Filtering records

```
bs.Filter= string.Format("column LIKE '%{0}%'", value);
```

**Why not List?**

List does not implement `IBindingList` so the grid does not know about your new items.

**Why not BindingList?**

You can not use `Filter` property to filter a `BindingSource` which it's DataSource is set to a `BindingList<T>`.

**How to use custom object?**

You can create a extended `BiningList<>` ([Refer this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DataGridView-Filter-db565575)).

Comment: Thank you much for detailed summary! I will try this at home and give feedback!

Comment: I used DataTable, thank you, seems to work realy fine!

Comment: Now i am allowed to vote up.. Did it now because you really helped me! Thank you again! Works still great.